# How to select a row in table using jquery?

Tags: jquery, select, html-table

I have created a table in my application, I want to select (change background color) whole row on click of a checkbox, same as gmail is doing, When we click checkbox in gmail, the whole row becomes yellow.

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="chk" id="chk" /></td>
<td>My Name</td>
<td>Description of the job</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Please tell me how to do the same in jquery?

Comment: To resolve this issues I have used the combination of @nickf and @cletus answers. Actually I want to develop the Select: All, None, Active and Inactive checkboxes, similar to what gmail is doing. So for single click I am able to select a row with @nickf's answer and for All and None I used the @cletus answer. So +1 for both.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$(function() {
  $("#chk").click(function() {
    $(this).parents("tr").toggleClass("diffColor");
  });
});
```

Create a CSS class (called "diffColor" above) and add the background color that way, something like:

```
<style type="text/css">
tr.diffColor td { background-color: yellow; }
</style>
```

Don't set CSS attributes directly. Use classes where possible.

Answer (score 5):

Cletus's answer is right, but I think can be improved a little:

```
$(function() {
    $("#chk").click(function() {
        $(this)
            .parents("tr:first")
            .toggleClass("diffColor", this.checked)
        ;
    });
});
```

The only real differences here is:

1. that it only selects the *first* parent `<tr>`. ...you never know where your code might end up, plus, in theory it'll be a couple of ticks faster.
2. it checks the new value of the checkbox and adds or removes the class as required. Without checking this, some other code might change the "diffColour" class on the row and then your checkbox would be inverted, if you know what i mean.

Also, you might consider binding that function to the `change` handler as well:

```
$('#chk').bind('click change', function() { // ... etc
```

Answer (score 0):

For selecting table rows you can use a simple class that I wrote called **TableRowSelector**.
Checkout the example and the example code [here](http://www.doublebow.net/articles/javascript/selecting-table-rows-in-javascript-with-tablerowselector)

Comment: your answer and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412001/select-table-row-in-jquery/6298535#6298535) are identical and are being flagged as potential spam. Whilst these answers may go some way to solving the OP's problem, you should tailor your answer to the question, summarise what your article is about and how it works and best of all provide a worked example. Thanks.