# Select Table Row in jQuery

Tags: jquery

What's the best way for selecting a table row by index using jQuery?

Thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you don't have to worry about nested tables:

```
$('#tableId tr').eq(4)
```

Comment: @Sahil http://api.jquery.com/eq/ It is (pretty much) the same as `$('#tableId tr:eq(4)')` or `$('#tableId tr')[4]`. It just means get the 5th element in the jQuery selection.

Answer (score 9):

You can do it all in the selector:

```
$('#tableId tr:eq(4)')
```

Comment: This works (and is faster) if you know the index ahead of time. However I always avoid the string concatenation within the selector that would be necessary to allow dynamic selection.