# Reselect highlighted row in datatable after page reload

Tags: jquery, datatable, highlight

I'm using a datatable where after clicking a row the page is reloaded with additional post parameters. What i'm trying to achieve is that after the page reload the selected row is highlighted again.

Snippets:

Jquery:

```
gTable = $('#goals').dataTable( { 
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "iDisplayLength":10,
    "sAjaxSource": "json_goals.php",
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "aoColumns" : [  null,null,null],
    "fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback ) {
         aoData.push( { "name": "missionId", "value": <?php echo $id; ?> } );
                $.ajax( {
                "dataType": 'json',
                "type": "GET",
                "url": sSource,
                "cache": false,
                "data": aoData,
                "success": fnCallback
            } );
        },
    "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex ) {
        if ( aData[0] == <?PHP echo $goalid; ?> ) { $('tr', nRow).addClass('highlight');} // this succeeds, tested with alert.
        return nRow;
        }
    });
```

CSS:

```
tr.highlight td{font-weight: bold;background-color: Yellow;}
```

HTML:

```
<table id="goals" class="display"><col style="width: 10%"/><col style="width: 20%"/><col style="width: 70%"/>
          <thead><tr>
          <th>goalId</th>
          <th>Goal Type</th>
          <th>Display Text</th>
          </tr></thead><tbody><tr><td colspan="3">Loading....</td></tr></tbody>
       </table>
```

Reload:

`$("#goals tbody tr").live('click',function(event) {
    $(gTable.fnSettings().aoData).each(function (){
       $(this.nTr).removeClass('row_selected');});
    $(event.target.parentNode).addClass('row_selected');
       var aData = gTable.fnGetData(this);
       window.location.replace("missions.php?goalid=" + aData[0] + "&id=" + <?PHP echo $id; ?> + "#tabs-5");});`

It's all working fine, except the row does not get highlighted.
Any ideas on how to approach this?
Thanks.

Comment: I don't see any code that reloads a page. I don't see any code that sends or receives additional POST parameters. I don't see any code that adds a click event to a table row. Why are you reloading the page? You're using AJAX elsewhere, so can you not use AJAX insrtead of reloading the page?

Comment: I added the reload code. The reason i do a POST is because depending on row selected 1 out of 17 different forms are shown. These forms are all dynamically loaded based on data from database. It was a lot easier for me to code it this way, mostly as i have never worked with ajax before ;)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your jQuery $() selector isn't getting a handle on your desired element. Try using `$('#goals tr').eq(nRow).addClass('highlight');`

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412001/select-table-row-in-jquery) for more information